# How to keep HAProxy TCP connection alive?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, rancher

I am having HAProxy in front of TCP servers like Postgres, Mongo and logstash. I am able to establish TCP connection but the connection will timeout after several minutes. Errors I'm getting are like

> Mongo::Error::SocketTimeoutError, Socket request timed out

and

> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>       before or while processing the request.

What can I do to keep TCP connection alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this help?

```
option srvtcpka
```